# Complex ordering in SSRS (Horizontally and Vertically)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been asked to create a report in SSRS with this layout:

[image]

…So I am first grouping by supplier, then by Month/Year, finally by Customer.

This is my main dataset, which returns the data I need (along with month and year dateparts for the above groupings)…

```
SELECT rvpo.SupplierName As [Supplier]
  , rvpoline.CustomerName As [Customer]
  , datepart(mm,rvpoline.DeliveryDate) As [Delivery Month]
  , datepart(yy,rvpoline.DeliveryDate) As [Delivery Year]
  , rvpo.Name As [PO #]
  , rvpoline.Quantity As [Quantity]
  , rvpoline.DeliveryDate As [Handover Date]
  FROM Finance.PurchaseOrderLine rvpoline
    JOIN Finance.PurchaseOrder rvpo on rvpo.Id = rvpoline.PurchaseOrderId
  ORDER BY 
    rvpo.SupplierName
  , DATEPART(YY, rvpoline.DeliveryDate) DESC
  , DATEPART(mm, rvpoline.DeliveryDate) DESC
  , rvpoline.CustomerName
```

…I am unsure how to set up my matrix to order this correctly (i.e. with the Supplier Grouping going downwards and the Month Grouping going across).

I suspect I will have to use a subreport for part of this (as if I use another table I will get a detail member cannot have inner members error), but I am unsure what values I should be passing  I just want to know if there is an easier way.

M

p.s. Am using SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of a matrix and a table to achieve the desired output.

1. Create a matrix and set the Column groupings to be your Month date, and the Row grouping to be the Supplier.
2. In the Data section, right click and select table to get a table nested inside this.  Set the values in the table to be Customer, Quality and Handover fields.  In design view this will look a bit like this

[image]

When you run it the following will be generated

[image]

By playing with the `BorderColor = Black`, and `BorderStyle = Solid` properties of the tablixes, you can fill in the missing edges.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Jonnus (I think I was just having a brain freeze moment here at work). Also right-clicking and inserting a table solves a lot of problems (I fully expected to get the "detail member etc." but it didn't show up), something to remember for the future.